# Host key verification failed - Linode

Tags: macos, ssh

I registered new Linode server. I am getting

> Host key verification failed

even after clearing up `known_hosts` file. I had already configured SSH to my friend's Linode server.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer "yes" (or simply "y") to the "Are you sure you want to continue connecting?" prompt.

Comment: I see one on the fourth line of the terminal (right below the blurred line).

Comment: Very sorry for this silly Question , i thought on clicking enter by default it will take yes. Thanks a lot.